# E/R model relationship

Tags: database, database-design, entity-relationship

Good Day,

I'm working on the task and Entity Relationship is new for me.I have just started. I have the following scenario and I have resolved this according to what I have understand so far.

We may think of relationships in the E/R model as having keys, just as entity sets do. Let R be a relationship among the entity sets E1, E2, …,En. Then a key for R is a set K of attributes chosen from the attributes of E1, E2,…, En such that if (e1,e2,…,en) and (f1,f2,…,fn) are two different tuples in the relationship set for R, then it is not possible that these tuples agree in all the attributes of K. Now, suppose n=2; that is, R is a binary relationship. Also, for each I, let Ki be a set of attributes that is a key for entity set Ei. In terms of E1 and E2, give a smallest possible key for R under the assumption that:

1. R is many-many
2. R is many-one from E1 to E2.
3. R is many-one from E2 to E1.
4. R is one-one.

For 2. I have solved this as following.

If R is many-one from E1 to E2, then two tuples (e1,e2) and (f1,f2) of the relationship set for R must be the same if they agree on the key attributes for E1. 
To see why, surely e1 and f1 are the same. Because R is many-one from E1 to E2, e2 and f2 must also be the same. Thus, the pairs are the same.

Could (3) one will be the same as (2) ? Also Could you please guide me or give me any clue about 1 and 4. Help will be appreciated.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're on the right track. Your reasoning in the solution for question 2 is correct - given that E1 determines E2, E1 is a minimal key for R. The same logic will apply to question 3.

In the case of question 1, E1 doesn't determine E2 or vice versa, so obviously neither can be a key on its own. In question 4, E1 determines E2 and E2 determines E1, so does it matter which you choose as key?